# SQLite Database Error(Glitch in bridge between two tables)

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have two tables as USER_TABLE where i have all the user details as **username,firstname** etc and similarly i have another table named `RESUME_TABLE` where i have **aim,degree,university** etc. 
The columns common to both are `KEY_USERID`(created dynamically) and i use this id to match the two tables.

**Question :**

I register a user and his details gets stored in the USER_TABLE and say his `KEY_USERID` automatically generated(primary key) is 1 and then i create a resume for him in the `RESUME_TABLE` using the same `KEY_USERID 1`. I pass on the `KEY_USERID` obtained from the first table as a argument while inserting and retrieving the resume contents from the `RESUME_TABLE`.

Say, i do this again for another user thereby generating `KEY_USERID 2` but i fill only the 
`USER_TABLE` and the **RESUME_TABLE IS EMPTY**.

When i repeat this again filling both the tables, then the `RESUME_TABLE` is not able to fetch the data cause the second user did not fill the details in `RESUME_TABLE` and that acts as a glitch while retrieving the `KEY_USERID` for the 3rd user.

How do i rectify this ?

---

**CODE :**

**DBAdapter.java :**

```
public String get_user_id(String name) {

        String[] column = new String[]{KEY_USERID};
        String where = KEY_USERNAME + "=?";
        Cursor c = mDB.query(DATABASE_TABLE, column, where,new String[]{""+ name + ""}, null, null,null);
        String user_id = "";
        int iuser_id = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_USERID);
        if (c != null)
            c.moveToFirst();
            user_id = user_id + c.getString(iuser_id) + "\t";
        c.close();
        return user_id;

    }
```

**ViewResume.java**

```
if(get_from_create!=null)
        {
            if(get_from_create.hasExtra("UserId_Create"))
            {
                String user_id_create = get_from_create.getExtras().getString("UserId_Create"); // This is where i get the user id from the first table which is created dynamically.
                dbAdapter.open();
                Log.i("In_View Resume_from_create",user_id_create);
                objective.setText(dbAdapter.getObjective(user_id_create));
                degree.setText(dbAdapter.getDegree(user_id_create));
                passed_out.setText(dbAdapter.getPassedOut(user_id_create));
                university.setText(dbAdapter.getUniversity(user_id_create));
                field.setText(dbAdapter.getField(user_id_create));
                years_of_experience.setText(dbAdapter.getyears_of_experience(user_id_create));
                areas_of_interest.setText(dbAdapter.getareas_of_interest(user_id_create));
                dbAdapter.close();
            }
```

**NOTE:**

`KEY_USERID` is auto incremented only for `USER_TABLE` and not for `RESUME_TABLE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have two automatic keys referring same elements on different tables.

You should only have automatic primary key in `USER_TABLE`. `KEY_USERID` can not be automatic, it must alwys be matched with `USER_TABLE.KEY_USERID` - effectively, a [foreign key](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html).

Furthermore, to understand why you are getting wrong id in code, you must post `get_from_create` function.

Comment: Thanks LS_dev. But get_from_create is an intent and am sorry cause i forgot to mention that. Also, are you implying that i should not add KEY_USERID in RESUME_TABLE as primary key ??